# Update another collection everytime a new document is inserted

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have two collections. As far as I can read (feel free to correct me if I am wrong) then you cannot join data between collections. So I am looking for the best approach to update one collection, every time documents are added to the other one. Lets take a simple sample:

Vessels:

```
[
    {
        "name": "vessel1",
        "id":1,
        "latestReportId":null,
        "latestReportName":null
    },
    {
        "name": "vessel2",
        "id":2,
        "latestReportId":null,
        "latestReportName":null
    }
]
```

Reports:
Reports

```
[
    {
        "name": "Report1",
        "id":1
    },
    {
        "name": "Report1",
        "id":1
    }
]
```

My first thought was using a trigger, but I read that trigger can only apply on the current partition. What is the right approach to do this? I can't be the only one that want relations between collections :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Cosmos DB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#trigger) in Azure Functions to sync both collections.

The Trigger can listen for changes in one collection and act (update/insert) data in another.

The full code sample and explanation is in this [article](https://medium.com/@Ealsur/azure-cosmos-db-functions-cookbook-live-migration-18ca3e60fda1), but basically you can create your trigger and tie it with an [Output Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#output) like so:

```
public static async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
    databaseName: "your-origin-database",
    collectionName: "your-origin-collection",
    ConnectionStringSetting = "your-origin-connectionstringsettings"
    ] IReadOnlyList<Document> documents,
    [CosmosDB("your-destination-database", 
    "your-destination-collection", 
    ConnectionStringSetting = "your-destination-connectionstringsettings")] IAsyncCollector<Document> saveDocuments,
    ILogger log)
{
    foreach (var doc in documents)
    {
        try
        {
            // do any transformation required to the original document
            await saveDocuments.AddAsync(doc); // You could also create a new document here based on information from the first one
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError($"Failed to process document id {doc.Id}: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is between databases. Does the same code apply just to update a property in another collection?

Comment: There is really not much documentation on trigger, mostly people recommend functions. I cant find any information on debugging them, and here it is stated they are not even triggered when adding new documents. Kind of strange something that simple, having a simple relation requires so much complexity.

Comment: @ThomasSegato just make the databases name and connection strings the same, I showed the more complete sample because it will help both scenarios. I'm not sure I understand the statement "not even triggered when adding new documents", that's the goal of the Cosmos DB Trigger. Do not mistake it with [Database Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming)

Comment: Okey I will give it a try. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are multiple docs covering this, you can take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/serverless-computing-database too.

Comment: Ahh now I think I understand. So your suggestion to use an Azure Function triggered by Cosmos DB. When I look in the Data Explorer under each collection there is a triggers node. When adding a trigger there it creates a file. I thought you added the logic there. What is that file for then?

Comment: That's for Database Triggers, Database Triggers need to be explicitly invoked and work in the context of that collection. Since you  mentioned you wanted to save information in another collection, I suggested Azure Functions. For more info on Database Triggers see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: matias would you decide to use a trigger over change feed?

Comment: @Marco The Cosmos DB Trigger uses the Change Feed. It leverages the Change Feed SDK. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed